# DSpace CRIS build failure

Tags: dspace

I am trying to deploy DSpace CRIS ver 5.x. Even after following guidelines provided on DSpace CRIS wiki, I am getting message of build failure. After referring one of the solution provided in forum, I also tried to download all maven dependencies in off-line mode. That is also getting failed in between.

Request help for deploying and checking DSpace CRIS.

Comment: Simple solution: fix the build failure. For more detailed help you'll have to provide a more detailed problem description which includes your setup, configuration, sequence of events and most of all the *exact* errors you get.

Comment: Build is getting failed while downloading dependencies from Maven. Download is getting failed in between, but if I go to the location manually in browser then able to reach that particular file. Similarly while trying to download dependencies using maven off-line mode command again it is getting interrupted in between. Will try to post error messages shortly.

Comment: Hi below are details appearing

Comment: Here is the link containing error message I am getting while preparing the DSpace CRIS build     https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rw8gEBsEmJ3Me8bUb2U0XCp5oK_5ei6G6mq3UEhXcNw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have used the "unstable" master branch to build DSpace-CRIS. The reccomended branch is (currently) dspace-cris-5.x.x
https://github.com/Cineca/DSpace/tree/dspace-5_x_x-cris

when a new version of the platform is released a new dspace--cris branch is created for maintenance and collaborative development is created too.

The dspace-cris-master branch is to make experiments when possible on unreleased version of DSpace.